# List showing in console

Tags: c#, list, console

I am adding 2items to my list and I want to look at them in console. But something went wrong, maybe you can help? I think main problem is in foreach loop. Where it says Part can not be found.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        public class DocPart
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string TexLine { get; set; }
    }
​
    public class DocConfig
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<DocPart> Parts { get; set; }
        DocConfig()
        {
            var doc = new DocConfig();
            doc.Description = "bla bla";
            doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "aaa", TexLine = @"\include{aaa.tex}" });
            doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "bbb", TexLine = @"\include{bbb.tex}" });
            this.Parts = new List<DocPart>();
                foreach (DocPart part in doc.Parts)
                       {
                Console.WriteLine(part.Title);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }  
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DocConfig));
​
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
            var config = (DocConfig)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
​
            return config;
        }
​
        public string SaveToString()
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DocConfig));
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be nice to have the complete code. there's no way of telling what went wrong like this.
We also have no idea what you're trying to achieve.
It would also help if you told us what kind of exception you're getting. (what's the message, what's the stack trace etc?)

Comment: You have a list of `DocParts`, but your foreach has `Part part in doc.Parts` instead of `DocPart part in doc.Parts`, or `var part in doc.Parts`. Unless Part is some base class, but without the rest of your code I can't make any assumptions about that.

Comment: Your class definitions should be outside of the main function. You are also trying to construct an object of type DocConfig inside the constructor of the DocConfig class. Probably worth finding a good resource regarding creating classes in C# before biting off more than you can chew. The question you are asking is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @TimothyGroote It is quite easy to see what is going wrong in this example. Its invalid C# code.

Comment: @JamesMoore there is *SO MUCH* going wrong, it's hard to tell what exactly OP is running into. solving problems is done one at a time ;)

Comment: I just edited complete code. Maybe you guys could give me some advice? I am just new to c# and want to make this project. First of all I have created list and want to check it, is it doing right.

Comment: @Mantas this still makes no sense, and there's no way this would even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use linq string.Join(",", my list)?